# React - fetching from API, how to skip the cors response

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-native, fetch

I want to make a simple POST request from my React app to my Spring back-end to authenticate the user. What i am doing :

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
      }),
    })
      .then(response => response.json()).then(resposne => console.log(resposne))
```

Trying to make this call will get me a  `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`. If i log the response i can see that it is a response with a `type:cors`. I assume i am getting the response from the OPTIONS request that goes out. How can i skip that response? If i check the headers on the response, the header that i want to get, which is the Authorization header, is non-existant. If i go to chrome devtools - network section, and look at the response i am getting, i can see the resposne is as it should be, and i can even see the token returned in the Authorization header. How can i access that header in my React app? Server is properly configured since it returns the token, i just cant get it in the React app.
[image]
 Thanks!

Comment: You should add the Access Control Expose Header with the Authorization header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: Consider this: `.then(response => response.json()).then(response => console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization')))`

Comment: @Christiaan adding Access Control Expose Header: Authorization to my spring filter did the trick. I can get the access token now. Feel free to leave it as answer so i can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the [Access Control Expose Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) with the Authorization header like so:

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems an error on the token generation. Did you take a look on Response body?

Seems like the response body is not a valid json.